# R How to combine dataframe factors with respect to their frequency

Tags: r, plot

I am pretty new to R, but a long time user of python. I've looked everywhere online, and have been struggling with something that seems like it should be so simple for a while.

So I have an R dataframe called "movement" of the form:

```
  person  activity
1    1    running
2    2    running
3    3    walking
4    4    flying
5    5    walking
6    6    running
```

Note: Person category doesn't mean "6 people are running", but "person #6 is running"

I need this as a descending bar graph, and I want to use basic R graphics. So, using the function bargraph(), with the persons as the "height", or frequency. The problem is, so far it will just treat the activities as individual, and spit out a graph of 6 bars with each activity listed separately.

I've tried so far using functions like rev(), sort(), order() to group the activities together, and descend the data. I've tried converting the dataframe to a matrix, or use the columns separately as vectors to satisfy the matrix/vector requirement of barplot(), but barplot(movement$person) just does what is stated above.

I've had the most luck so far converting the dataframe to a table, and using it like so:

```
bargraph(table(movement))
```

However, this doesn't give me the data in descending form, and I couldn't figure out how to make the table descended. I get a graph like this:

[image: PLOT]

I would want this from left to right to go: Running, Walking, Flying.

Is there a simple way of doing this, or do I need to restructure the whole dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to `factor` with `levels` specified

```
movement$activity <- factor(movement$activity, levels = unique(movement$activity))
```

and then do `barplot`

```
barplot(table(movement))
```

#### data

```
movement <- structure(list(person = 1:6, activity = c("running", "running", 
"walking", "flying", "walking", "running")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this did solve my issue. I understand the "levels", but what exactly is unique() doing?

Comment: @Destroxia  Suppose, you have a vector `v1 <- c('a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'b'); unique(v1)#[1] "a" "b" "d"` .  In the dataset, you want the order to be in the `'running', 'walking', 'flying'` which happens to be aligned with the same order of `unique` elements.

Comment: @Destroxia If the order happened by chance, then you can change the levels by first getting the frequency of activity `tbl <- table(movement$activity); movement$activity <- factor(movement$activity, levels = names(sort(tbl, decreasing = TRUE)))`